# converting json array into normal array by using jq

Tags: json, shell, parsing, jq

```
{
   "name": "ford",
   "availableVersions": [
      {
         "version": 111,
         "count": 3
      },
      {
         "version": 122,
         "count": 2
      },
      {
         "version": 133,
         "count": 3
      },
      {
         "version": 144,
         "count": 1
      }
                          ],
       "RealVersion": 155


}
{
   "name": "bmw",
   "availableVersions": [
     {
         "version": 244,
         "count": 1
     },
     {
      "version": 255,
      "count": 3
     }                  ],
     "RealVersion": 120

    }
```

I have this demo.json file now `if (name == 'ford')`(name can be a variable) I want to get the all the versions whose `count != 3`
and if all the version's `count == 3` I want to get the RealVersion of ford so in this case output should be.

`EXPECTED OUTPUT = [122 144 ]`
I am using jq tool for parsing the json file

Now if all the version count ==3

```
      {
   "name": "ford",
   "availableVersions": [
      {
         "version": 111,
         "count": 3
      },
      {
         "version": 122,
         "count": 3
      },
      {
         "version": 133,
         "count": 3
      },
      {
         "version": 144,
         "count": 3
      }
                          ],
       "RealVersion": 155


}
{
   "name": "bmw",
   "availableVersions": [
     {
         "version": 244,
         "count": 1
     },
     {
      "version": 255,
      "count": 3
     }                  ],
     "RealVersion": 120

    }
```

Now in this case all the version's count == 3 so now I want to get the real version which is 155
`EXPECTED OUTPUT SHOULD BE 155`

I am using this command

```
    cat demo | jq  '.RealVersion as $RealVersion | select(.name == "bmw") | .availableVersions |  map(select(.count != 3)) |  if length > 0 then map(.version) else $RealVersion end'
```

which worked fine but it is returning a json array if there is more than one element. But i want to store it in a normal array. I think if i don't use map then it will work. I want the output so that i can store it in an normal array . Can anybody help me with this?

Comment: What do you mean a *normal array*?

Comment: Output should not be in the form of an json array. Right now it is giving me an output like this  `  [
  122,
  144
] `
 I want all the version should be space seperated so I can store them in an array. I want output to be like this 122 144 only space seperated

Comment: Then why don't you `join` them?

Comment: I dont know the method can you please help me?

Answer (score 0):

Using `join` and then a string concatenation at the end to add the brackets ...

```
jq --compact-output --raw-output '.RealVersion as $RealVersion | select(.name == "ford") | .availableVersions | map(select(.count != 3)) | if length > 0 then map(.version) else $RealVersion end | join (" ") | "[" + . + "]"'
```

```
[122 144]
```

[Try it online!](https://jqplay.org/s/yVTGK-wwph)

Also, since you probably don't want to hardcode the brand of car, you can use `--arg` and make that a variable. Simple example of `--arg`

```
$ jq -n --arg brand "ford" '{"brand": $brand}'

{
  "brand": "ford"
}
```

(the `-n` flag just tells jq that this command doesn't use any input, because this is a simple exanmple)

Hope this helps!